# Show that a set of open intervals can be formed by the countable union of sequences of rationals.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I recently decided to get into probability theory. I am following Jacod and Protter, "Probability Essentials".

One of the first theorems (T.2.1) uses  the following :

Let $C$ denote all open intervals in $\mathbb R$. Let $(a, b)$ be part of $C$.
Consider a sequence of rationals strictly decreasing to $a$ and a sequence of rationals strictly increasing to $b$ ( $a_n$ and $b_n$ ).

$$(a , b) = \bigcup_{n=1}( a_n , b_n]$$

I am a bit rusty on this. But why is the interval $( a_n , b_n]$ closed on the right ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should precise that the sequence $(b_n)$ must be *strictly* increasing, otherwise the result is not true (take $a=0$, $b=1$, and $a_n=0$ and $b_n=1$ for all $n$. Then $(a,b)=(0,1) \neq (0,1]=\cup (a_n,b_n]$).

Comment: The union is $(a,b)$ regardless of whether the endpoints of the intervals are included or not. I'm sure they're using semi-open intervals only because finite unions of those form an algebra, which is a nice structure in probability theory.